# Writing to file without curly brackets

Tags: export

When u write a list into a file, like in the example below

```
list={{1,2},{2,1},{1,3},{4,2},{4,1}};
myfile=OpenWrite["C:\\myfile.txt"];
Table[Write[myfile,list[[i]]],{i,1,Length[list]}];
```

The output u get is:

```
{1,2}
{2,1}
{1,3}
{4,2}
{4,1}
```

The output I wish to have is:

```
1 2 2 1 1 3 4 2 4 1
```

I cannot export the whole list as in my work I need to print things on the go, so the structure of the `write` command need to be the same unless u have an alternative

Comment: You might use [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html) to write the file out in [`CSV`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/CSV.html) format.

Comment: @m_goldberg  I would prefer to keep this structure, in my code there is a function that gives output to a vector with length 2 and the list length is very very long, so to save time I wish to print to the file on the go

Comment: Can you be explicit in terms of the output you need? Is it only for a `list` of precisely these dimensions or does this need to be more flexible? (Either way, please add all additional information as edits to the post rather than comments under it as those can be deleted at any time.)

Comment: @EmilioPisanty, edited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Write` writes expressions out in InputForm, so you really need to use [`WriteString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WriteString.html)

```
With[{delimiter = " "},
  helper[strm_, {x_, y_}] := WriteString[strm, x, delimiter, y, delimiter]]

With[{
    data = {{1, 2}, {2, 1}, {1, 3}, {4, 2}, {4, 1}},
    file = FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "data.txt"}]},
  Module[{out},
    out = OpenWrite[file]; 
    AbortProtect[helper[out, #] & /@ data; Close[out]]]]

FilePrint[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "data.txt"}]]
```

> `1 2 2 1 1 3 4 2 4 1`

Comment: Actually `Write` uses `FormatType` of the specified output channel which for `OpenWrite` by default has `FormatType -> InputForm`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov. Good point. I edited the answer to conform.